# How to make noise generation for images faster?

Tags: python, image, numpy, random, noise-generator

I'm making an image iterator for my deep learning project. On this project, i need to apply noise generation(for reducing overfitting).

I tried the code below, but it takes 0.005 seconds for one image, yes it is fast but i'm working with more than a million images, so it takes a lot to do that.

```py
def noise_generator(img, n=0.15):
 return img + np.random.normal(0.0, n, img.shape)
```

It would be really good if i can do it in like 0.001 seconds for one image. Any suggestions?

Comment: How important is the quality of the noise?

Comment: what is slow? generating the noise? Pregenerate 100 noises and use one of them. adding the noise to the image? Where is the bottleneck?

Comment: It is 0.0005 per image now, thanks again ^^

Answer (score 0):

In keras framework you can add a layer to your model to perform gaussian noise `keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev)`. So something like this :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, GaussianNoise, Input

model = Sequential()
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.5, input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.summary()
```

Comment: is computing gaussian noise faster then computing np.random.normal(0.0, n, img.shape)?